# Creating physics bodies for each side of a given SpriteNode in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skspritenode

I am making a simple game where objects fall from the top of the screen and land on the ground at the bottom of the screen (kind of like tetris), where the player is on the ground avoiding and destroying the objects as they land. I want the player to be able to destroy the objects when it touches the left and right sides, and I want the player to be killed when the object falls onto of him. I also want the player to be able to jump ontop of the objects without destroying them.

I am trying to figure out the correct coordinates in order to make a physics body for each side of my objects. (here is some code I was working with to try and do this):

```
        let topLeftPoint = CGPointMake(1, (objectSprite.size.height))
        let bottomLeftPoint = CGPointMake(1 , 1)
        let topRightPoint = CGPointMake((objectSprite.size.width), (objectSprite.size.height))
        let bottomRightPoint = CGPointMake((objectSprite.size.width), 1)


        self.topSideBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: topLeftPoint, toPoint: topRightPoint)
        self.topSideBody.categoryBitMask = ObstacleSide.topSide.rawValue
        self.topSideBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue | BodyType.grassObject.rawValue


        self.leftSideBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: topLeftPoint, toPoint: bottomLeftPoint)
        self.leftSideBody.categoryBitMask = ObstacleSide.leftSide.rawValue
        self.leftSideBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue | BodyType.grassObject.rawValue

        self.rightSideBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: topRightPoint, toPoint: bottomRightPoint)
        self.rightSideBody.categoryBitMask = ObstacleSide.rightSide.rawValue
        self.rightSideBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue | BodyType.grassObject.rawValue

        self.bottomSideBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: bottomLeftPoint, toPoint: bottomRightPoint)
        self.bottomSideBody.categoryBitMask = ObstacleSide.bottomSide.rawValue
        self.bottomSideBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue | BodyType.grassObject.rawValue

        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [topSideBody, leftSideBody, rightSideBody, bottomSideBody])
        objectSprite.physicsBody = physicsBody
        //objectSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.grassObject.rawValue
        objectSprite.physicsBody!.friction = 0.0
        objectSprite.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
        objectSprite.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true

        objectSprite.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.0
        objectSprite.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

        self.zPosition = 102
```

I am mainly unsure on what coordinates I should be using, or if there is a easier way to do this. I also have no issue destroying the obstacles and killing the player given some of the boolean values I have set for the obstacles, my main issue is the player being able to walk ontop of the objects without destroying them.

Comment: If you want to respond to each body collision differently, like dying when hitting bottomSideBody, and just colliding when hitting topSideBody, then you'll need to create 4 separate SKNodes (you can bundle them together with a common parent). Using SKPhysicsBody(bodies:) takes the union of the given bodies collision areas, and combines them into a single body, you will not be able to later distinguish between "sub-bodies".

Comment: Also your point values should be anchored at 0. let topLeftPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.size.height) ...

Comment: @cpimoff So i figured out the correct coordinates and created 4 separate SKPhysicsBodys to make up the physics body for my object/obstacle. I am now having issues with collision between the obstacles themselves (objectSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [topSideBody, leftSideBody, rightSideBody, bottomSideBody]) is what makes up my object/obstacle node). I have tried giving my objectSprite a categoryBitMask to deal with its collisions, but that doesn't seem to work. and when I assign individual bit masks to the sides, I can't seem to get them to collide either

Comment: If you're still combining all the individual physics bodies with `SKPhysicsBody(bodies:)` then their individual bit masks and such will all go ignored, which may explain why they aren't colliding as intended. That constructor _only_ takes in the bodies collision bounds, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need more then 1 physics body if the objects are square or rectangle. This is a general outline of how you would do it:

**NOTE that I copied most of the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986417/align-spritenode-with-surface-on-collision-spritekit-swift3). I suggest you read it to get a better understanding of whats going on**

in your didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) function.

Get the object node and the collisionPoint (lets assume that the object is the contact.bodyB.node) and pass it to the function below:

```
let block = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode
let contactPoint = contact.contactPoint


func handleCollision(block:SKSpriteNode, contactPoint:CGPoint){
        // find the corners and convert thoes points into the scene coordinate space
        let topLeft = convert(CGPoint(x: -block.size.width/2, y: block.size.height/2), from: block)
        let bottomLeft = convert(CGPoint(x: -block.size.width/2, y: -block.size.width/2), from: block)
        let topRight = convert(CGPoint(x: block.size.width/2, y: block.size.height/2), from: block)
        let bottomRight = convert(CGPoint(x: block.size.width/2, y: -block.size.width/2), from: block)

        // Then we put these "referencePoints" into an array for easy acces.
        // Note that we go in a clockwise direction from the top left

        let referencePoints = [topLeft,topRight,bottomRight,bottomLeft]

        // ***Find the closest corner relative to the contactPoint.***

        // Varible to store the closetCorner
        var closestCorner = referencePoints[0]

        //We set the prevDistance to something very large.
        var prevDistance:CGFloat = 10000000

        for corner in referencePoints{

            // We check the distance from the contactPoint to each corner.
            // If the distance is smaler then the last checked corner we update the closestCorner varible and also the prevDistance.
            let distance = hypot(corner.x - contactPoint.x, corner.y - contactPoint.y)
            if distance < prevDistance{
                prevDistance = distance
                closestCorner = corner
            }

        }

        // Now lets find the NextCorner and prevCorner relative to the closestCorner.
        var nextCorner:CGPoint
        var prevCorner:CGPoint
        let index = referencePoints.index(of: closestCorner)

        if index == 3{
            nextCorner = referencePoints[0]
        }
        else{
            nextCorner = referencePoints[index! + 1]
        }

        if index == 0{

            prevCorner = referencePoints[3]

        }
        else{
            prevCorner = referencePoints[index! - 1]
        }



        // Distance from closestCorner to nextCorner.
        let distToNextCorner = hypot(closestCorner.x - nextCorner.x, closestCorner.y - nextCorner.y)
        // Distance from contactPoint to nextCorner
        let distFromContactPoint = hypot(contactPoint.x - nextCorner.x, contactPoint.y - nextCorner.y)



        let firstSurfacePoint = closestCorner
        var secondSurfacePoint:CGPoint

        if distToNextCorner > distFromContactPoint{

            secondSurfacePoint = nextCorner

        }
        else{
            secondSurfacePoint = prevCorner

        }


        if firstSurfacePoint == topLeft || firstSurfacePoint == topRight &&
            secondSurfacePoint == topLeft || secondSurfacePoint == topRight  {

            // collision happend on the top side. Do something here to handle that

        }

        if firstSurfacePoint == topRight || firstSurfacePoint == bottomRight &&
            secondSurfacePoint == topRight || secondSurfacePoint == bottomRight  {

            // collision happend on the right side. Do something here to handle that

        }

        if firstSurfacePoint == bottomLeft || firstSurfacePoint == bottomRight &&
            secondSurfacePoint == bottomLeft || secondSurfacePoint == bottomRight  {

            // collision happend on the underside. Do something here to handle that

        }

        if firstSurfacePoint == topLeft || firstSurfacePoint == bottomLeft &&
            secondSurfacePoint == topLeft || secondSurfacePoint == bottomLeft  {

            // collision happend on the left side. Do something here to handle that

        }

    }
```

*This answer might be a little bit sloppy, but if someone askes I can refine it. didn't really bother since the question is 11 months old :)*